# display number of emails sent using php mail function

Tags: php, email, count, echo

I am creating a real-estate website that displays properties. On each property listing I would like a button that says 'Express Interest', when clicked, this button should send an email to me containing the user details who expressed interest (the user will be logged in and so all their details will be taken from their account).

I have the email function working fine, HOWEVER, I also want to display the number of people who have 'Expressed Interest'. Is there a way to track how many times an email has been sent using this button and display "xx people have expressed interest in this property"

Answer (score 1):

Store in the database before sending the mail and just before sending the mail include the number of people or the people who are interested, a simple query would suffice, or if you have a content management system you can include it there, in both cases you would need an intermediate table (connection between user id and real-estate id)

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer, can you possibly give me just a little more direction on how to do this? Or even just what to search for. Thanks

Comment: I would start with the intermetiate table, on click insert the user`s id and the real estate id and just before sending the mail you can query the database (either a count where the real-estate id is the one the user selected or inner join on users table to get all the user`s information)

Comment: Thanks KA_lin. Unfortunately this is still a little beyond me, I found this piece of code on another forum. Currently it doesn't work, is there anyway it could help?

`code` <?php
    $count = 0;
    while ($condition) {
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message))
            $count++;
    }
    echo "Totally, $count messages have been sent!";
?>

Answer (score 0):

I would add another table to your database that stores a property_id and a user_id. If a user clicks expresses interest, you add another row to that table with the current property_id and the current user_id. To get the amount of links you simply count the rows

```
SELECT count(user_id) FROM interest_relation WHERE property_id = 'your property id'
```

This way you can also find out which user is interested in which property.